# Is it possible to run two SharePoint instances on one server?

Tags: sharepoint

Simple question : Is it possible to run two SharePoint instances on one server?

With a not so simple answer I suspect.

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three answers:

A server can only be connected to one "config database", meaning you can only run one FARM instance.

A server can host multiple SSPs, so you can run multiple SEARCH, USER PROFILE, MY SITE instances. Not recommended though.

A server can host as many web applications (websites) as you'd like.

Comment: Thanks, not what I wanted to hear though as now we need to buy two servers along with all the licensing. The idea was to have an extranet and an intranet running on SharePoint. But I don't want SharePoint to be in charge of separating the two security wise...

Comment: SharePoint can work for intranet+extranet scenarios on the same farm. Then again there's no reason to put in on the same farm unless you want to expose the SAME information to the extranet. I think a lot of people get into trouble trying to customize ONE FARM TO RULE THEM ALL when they could just make a bunch of farms and save configuration headaches.

Comment: Sounds like a typical SharePoint answer... "You chose SharePoint because you thought it was verbose, but it actually sucks and you can't accomplish simple things that you'd think are obvious."

Answer (score 1):

We've been running multiple instances on different ports, no problem. Great for development. But we haven't been running different versions of SharePoint on the same server

Comment: We're running SP Foundation 2010, and we have two DB servers, one for each instance of SP, but I do not know how to install two instances on the same IIS. Also, I do not want these instances to be on the same farm. They really are two SP sites. One will be for dev and the other for test. I read that only one server can host one farm, so does that mean the SP instances have to be installed as Standalone? Thanks for any help.

Comment: @niklassers - I configured two instances. I created a new top level web app from Central Administration -> Application Management -> Manage Web Applications. Is this how you did it?

Answer (score 1):

You can run multiple web apps on the same server, provided they use different ports and / or different host headers.  They will both be part of the same farm however...

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by two SharePoint 2007 instances two installations of the server, then the answer would be no. If you mean two completely different sites with different sitenames, that is possible by making use of hostheaders for each of your web applications. 
Running SharePoint 2003 and SharePoint 2007 side by side is possible. I haven't tested running SharePoint 2010 next to SharePoint 2007/2003 though.