# How to create new Farm in Share Point 2010 on single server?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I want to create new Farm on Share Point 2010 server.I have already one Farm on same Share Point 2010 server and want to create new Farm on same server.
So I require multiple farm working on same sharepoint2010 server.
Is it possible to create new Farm ? Please help me out.
Please provide step to create new Farm if possible to create.

Comment: So is for programming questions. Consider posting on superuser.

Comment: @icbytes: No this is SharePoint 2010 product configuration. I think programming is not required for this question. May be we can use power shell script.

Comment: This forum is for programming.

Comment: running everything on one server isn't ideal in the first place, What is the reason behind this? we only use this sort of setup for development environments. Maybe if you could post this elsewhere as suggested by icbytes.

Comment: Thank you Truezplaya... I already asked this question in "Share Point" blog, but in this forum we have also great people who knows about this type of issue.So if anybody knows then they would reply it.

Answer (score 1):

here are two discussing on this question already on stackoverflow:

[Is it possible to run two SharePoint instances on one server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764661/is-it-possible-to-run-two-sharepoint-instances-on-one-server)

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/25074/multiple-instances-of-sharepoint-2010-on-one-machine-development-and-staging

And a good post about SP Farms:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/martinkearn/archive/2008/03/13/useful-facts-about-sharepoint-farms.aspx